# Jackson JSON Serialization: Is there a way to somehow apply jackson.annotation.JsonRawValue annotation to every map entry but not map itself?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm working on JSON serialization in Java. I'm struggling with special characters auto escaping. Both gson and jackson do it and it is hard to omit. jackson.annotation.JsonRawValue seems to be working for simple String fields but it fails during Map serialization.

I have field in my POJO:

```
Map<String,String> properties;
```

and I want values in this map to not be changed at all during serialization.

using  @JsonRawValue on top of whole map like here:

```
@JsonRawValue
    public Map<String, String> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }
```

results in creation of invalid json string, because map will be serialized to something like that:

```
"properties" : {prop1=val1, prop2=val2, prop3=val3},
```

instead of double-quoted strings:

```
"properties" : {"prop1"="val1", "prop2"="val2", "prop3"="val3"},
```

but if any value will contain for example backslash it will be doubled which is what I'm trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: Could you give an example of value which `Jackson` changes during serialisation?

Comment: String ```"something\'something"``` will be changed to ```"something\\\'something"```

Comment: Which version of `Jackson` do you use?

Comment: version of ```Jackson``` that I'm using is 2.9.8